# Java IO outperforms Java NIO when it comes to file reading

Tags: java, time, io, nio

I believed that the new `nio` package would outperform the old `io` package when it comes to the time required to read the contents of a file. However, based on my results, `io` package seems to outperform `nio` package. Here's my test:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileTestingOne {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        File file = new File("hey2.txt");
        try {
            byte[] a = direct(file);
            String s = new String(a);
        }
        catch (IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = (endTime - startTime);
        System.out.println(totalTime);
    }

    public static ByteBuffer readFile_NIO(File file) throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile rFile = new RandomAccessFile(file.getName(), "rw");
        FileChannel inChannel = rFile.getChannel();

        ByteBuffer _buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        int bytesRead = inChannel.read(_buffer);
        while (bytesRead != -1) {
            _buffer.flip();
            while (_buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                byte b = _buffer.get();
            }
            _buffer.clear();
            bytesRead = inChannel.read(_buffer);
        }

        inChannel.close();
        rFile.close();
        return _buffer;
    }

    public static byte[] direct(File file) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        return buffer;
    }

    public static byte[] readFile_IO(File file) throws IOException {

        byte[] _buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        InputStream in = null;

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
            if ( in.read(_buffer) == -1 ) {
                throw new IOException(
                        "EOF reached while reading file. File is probably empty");
            }
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (in != null)
                    in.close();
            }
            catch (IOException err) {
                // TODO Logging
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return _buffer;
    }



}

// Small file
//7566395  -> readFile_NIO
//10790558 -> direct
//707775   -> readFile_IO

// Large file
//9228099  -> readFile_NIO
//737674   -> readFile_IO
//10903324 -> direct

// Very large file
//13700005  -> readFile_NIO
//2837188   -> readFile_IO
//11020507  -> direct
```

Results are:

- Small file:

  - `nio` implementation: 7,566,395ns
  - `io` implementation: 707,775ns
  - direct implementation: 10,790,558ns
- Large file:

  - `nio` implementation: 9,228,099ns
  - `io` implementation: 737,674ns
  - direct implementation: 10,903,324ns
- Very large file:

  - `nio` implementation: 13,700,005ns
  - `io` implementation: 2,837,188ns
  - direct implementation: 11,020,507ns

I wanted to ask this question because (I believe) `nio` package is non-blocking, thus it needs to be faster, right?

Thank you,

#### Edit:

Changed ms to ns

Comment: Also try with a bigger buffer (at least 1 MB). It's nano seconds (ns). Also compare with `new FileInputStream(file).getChannel()`, instead of using `RandomAccessFile`. And do some meaningful work, like reading the contents to a String.

Comment: Do you clear the filesystem cache before you measure the time of each method? Otherwise your measurements will not be comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory mapped files (or `MappedByteBuffer`) are a part of Java NIO and could help improve performance.

The non-blocking in Java NIO means that a thread does not have to wait for the next data to read. It does not necessarily affect performance of a full operation (like reading *and* processing a file) at all.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!